# Who killed the Comanche raiders?

Tags: plot-explanation, hostiles

In the movie, Hostiles, Christian Gale and his party are attacked by a group of Comanche raiders whose leader had his face painted in red and black.

This Comanche leader is seen killed and his body hangs from a tree.

Who could have killed them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yellow Hawk and Black Hawk

> After this attack, Yellow Hawk convinces Blocker that it is in everyone's best interest to unchain him and his family. The next day, the bodies of the surviving Comanche party, who had managed to flee during their previous encounter, are discovered dead. Blocker deduces that Yellow Hawk and his son, Black Hawk, killed them thanks to Metz allowing them to leave the camp during the night.
> <sub><sup>*- [Hostiles(film) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostiles_(film))*</sup></sub>

If not this he was killed during the initial conflict.

Comment: @Yu Zhang did this not answer your question?